# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

This error has been asked about A LOT. But none of the cases I think apply to my particular case, or at least not quite.

I am creating a new entity with 2 navigation properties that are collections. Both the entity and the navigation properties are new entities that do not exist in the database. My problem is that whenever I try to attach the entity to the context, if either of the collections has more than 1 element I get to aforementioned exception.

I am getting this error on the `Attach()` instruction in the following code:

```
using (var context = new NSModel())
{
    context.Notifications.Attach(e);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(e,
    StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(e.State));

    foreach (NavigationProperty1 np in e.NavigationProperty1s)
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(np,
        StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(np.State));

    foreach (NavigationProperty2 np in e.NavigationProperty2s)
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(np,
        StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(np.State));

    context.SaveChanges();
    return e;
}
```

The code is for a web site so the entities are stateless and the context is created and disposed of with every call...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both the entity and the navigation properties are new entities that do
>   not exist in the database.

Then the question is: Why do you use `Attach`? By using `Attach` you tell EF that the entites *are* in the database and EF will consider the values of the primary key properties as the PK column values in the database. Because those properties must be unique EF will complain as soon as you have two entites with the same key values. It's well possible that you have this situation when you have autogenerated identities as key properties and don't set the values when you create the entities.

Simple example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This code ...

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    var child1 = new Child();   // <- Id is 0
    var child2 = new Child();   // <- Id is 0 as well

    parent.Children.Add(child1);
    parent.Children.Add(child2);

    ctx.Parents.Attach(parent);  // <- exception here

    //...
}
```

... will throw your exception because EF tries to attach two different child instances with the same key `0`. When the second child `child2` will get attached it says: "An object (namely `child1`) with the same key (namely `0`) already exists in the ObjectStateManager".

If you want to add the whole object graph as new entities to the database you could just call `context.Notifications.AddObject(e);` instead of `Attach`.

Comment: Thx... I actually got it working using attach() but your solutions is cleaner and more elegant.